# Can I use RVM to manage my ruby versions together? How does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

The situation is like this:
1: I have a project that I have been writing. It is more than half finished using ruby 1.9.2,  rails 2.3.11, and rubygems 1.3.7.

2: Now, I would like to make a new app with Rails 3. Online searches say that Rails 3.2 + ruby 1.9.3 is pretty good. So, for this project, I upgraded the environment to Ruby ​​1.9.3, Rails 3.2, and rubygems 1.8.17.

3: But now my original project no longer works, and then I began to modify the original project in Rails 3 is not compatible with the place, changed with the change found that I have too many mistakes and are not compatible. I've heard that too Rvm but have not used just know that is used to manage ruby Rails version.

4: Can I have an environment for working with my original app (ruby1.9.2 rails 2.3.11 rubygems 1.3.7) and still upgrade to the modern stuff (rails3.2 ruby ​​1.9.3 rubygems 1.8.17) for developing new apps?

5: What have you and your colleagues used? What are your ideas and feelings about what you use? Do you have have any good suggestions?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question. Install rvm and the bundler gem to take care of your gem dependencies.

Comment: now i just use homebrew install ruby so taht my ruby verssion is 1.9.2,and i development a web app with i and rails 2.3.11 . but now i want to use rails 3 + ruby 1.9.3 development web app , so taht i need manage my ruby verssion with rvm ! my question is rvm can for me with my situation?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Install rvm, use it to install the versions of ruby that you want. In each project, make a .rvmrc file with contents like

```
rvm --rvmrc --create ruby-1.9.3-p125@project_name
```

This will switch the rubies when you cd into the directory (the first time it sees this file, it will ask you to validate that you want to use it). And it will swap out what gems you are using so that you can have unique sets of gems loaded in each environment (though if you use Bundler properly, you don't really need this feature)

[here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/#project) is more about per-project .rvmrc files.

Comment: @mr.li it's a good practice to accept an answer if it solves your problem